# React sub list won't render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create nested list in React but for some reason only the top list renders and not the children for the item in the list. Here is my code any help would be appreciated as I been stuck on this for a while.

```
import React from 'react';

import OutbreakItem from './OutbreakItem';
import ListHeader from './ListHeader';

var OutbreakList = React.createClass({

  renderOutbreakHeader: function(key) {
    return (
      <ListHeader key={key} county={this.props.outbreaks[key].county}>
        {this.props.outbreaks[key].outbreaks.map(this.renderOutbreak)}
      </ListHeader>
    );
  },

  renderOutbreak: function(object, i) {
    return <OutbreakItem key={object.recordId} outbreak={object} />
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container body-content">
        {Object.keys(this.props.outbreaks).map(this.renderOutbreakHeader)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default OutbreakList;
```

The Outbreak Item;

```
import React from 'react';

var OutbreakItem = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container outbreak-item">
          <a href="#">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4 outbreak-item-main-text">{this.props.outbreak.facility}</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-main-text">{this.props.outbreak.declaredDate}</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-normal-text">{this.props.outbreak.admittingDate}</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-main-text">{this.props.outbreak.duration} days</div>
                <div className="col-md-2"><span className="label label-warning">{this.props.outbreak.pathogen}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4 outbreak-item-sub-text">{this.props.outbreak.location}, {this.props.outbreak.type}</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-sub-normal-text">Date Closed</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-sub-normal-text">Admissions Opened</div>
                <div className="col-md-2 outbreak-item-sub-text">Outbreak Duration</div>
                <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default OutbreakItem;
```

The ListHeader

```
import React from 'react';

var ListHeader = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row outbreak-item-header">
              <div className="col-md-12">{this.props.county}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default ListHeader;
```

The list headers print but not the outbreak items. In debug I can see the renderOutbreak function get called with the correct values but it's not rendered out.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the issue was. I was rendering the OutbreakItem inside the ListHeader. I needed to render it after the list header. Here is the corrected code.

```
import React from 'react';

import OutbreakItem from './OutbreakItem';
import ListHeader from './ListHeader';

var OutbreakList = React.createClass({

  renderOutbreakHeader: function(key) {
    return (
      <div>
        <ListHeader key={key} county={this.props.outbreaks[key].county} />
        {this.props.outbreaks[key].outbreaks.map(this.renderOutbreak)}
      </div>
    );
  },

  renderOutbreak: function(object, i) {
    return <OutbreakItem key={object.recordId} outbreak={object} />
  },

  render: function() {

    return (
      <div className="container body-content">
        {Object.keys(this.props.outbreaks).map(this.renderOutbreakHeader)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default OutbreakList;
```